# JavaFX Native Packaging EXE on a Mac

Tags: windows, macos, javafx, exe, javafx-8

I am using Eclipse on Mac to develop my JavaFX application. I have packaged it as a dmg very nicely with the ant build and e(fx)clipse plugin.

However I now need to make this application an exe. Every tutorial and help I have found so far show that you need Inno Setup however this program is only available for Windows and I am on a Mac.

How should I go about this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, you cannot make an .exe file on a Mac with the javapackager tool. You may want to use a Virtual Machine with Windows. In Windows you need Inno Setup for .exe and Wix Toolset for .msi creation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible, as documented at official oracle website:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html

> Self-contained application packages have the following drawbacks:
>
> - Package per target platform: Self-contained application packages are platform-specific and can only be produced for the same system on
>     which you build. To deliver self-contained application packages on
>     Windows, Linux, and OS X, you must build your project on all three
>     platforms.

Creating native bundles/launchers is tied to internal tools calling local installed toolsets, so running any "EXE"-file would never work. An option would be to install a windows-system inside some virtual machine.

Some notes about "create 32bit on 64bit"-systems and vice-versa: it is tricky and not very possible, at least on windows-systems. I encountered this while debugging [some issue of the javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/81) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer of that maven-plugin)